A variation on the concept of product: Are there some examples of categories where this concept is interesting?
This is a little bit of a random question; I am just curious:
The product $X \times Y$ of objects $X$ and $Y$ in a category $\mathscr C$ can be seen as the terminal object in the category of "pre-products" of $X$ and $Y$. This is what I mean by this: A "pre-product" of $X$ and $Y$ is to be understood here as a tuple $\langle P, \pi_1, \pi_2 \rangle$ where $P$ is an object of $\mathscr C$ with $\pi_1 : P \rightarrow X$ and $\pi_2 : P \rightarrow Y$ morphisms. (So basically a span.) A morphism from $\langle P, \pi_1, \pi_2\rangle$ to $\langle P', \pi_1', \pi_2' \rangle$ is a morphism $f : P \rightarrow P'$ such that $\pi'_i f = \pi_i$ for $i = 1, 2$.
Now, what I am interested in is the initial object of this category. Is there any interesting instance of such an object, in some category? Clearly, if $\mathscr C$ has an initial object, then this gives us the initial object in category of "pre-products" for any pair of objects $X$ and $Y$. So, the concept is clearly quite meaningless in $\mathbf{Set}$, $\mathbf{Grp}$, etc., which have an initial object.

This more general question is related, though that thread doesn't seem to have produced any interesting examples.

Your category of preproducts is just the category of cones over your diagram that defines your limit. Maybe study this in the category of simplicial sets the products are interesting

@julio_es_sui_glace $\mathrm{sSet}$ has an initial object and so the notion is trivial, as Jan points out.

Then a useful one would be the category of fields, but it does not have products…

I don't think the lack of products is an obstacle to the existence of initial pre-products. However the category of fields seems "trivial" for the same reason: in this case its connected components (fields of a given characteristic) each have an initial object (the prime field of that characteristic). So $X$ and $Y$ have an initial pre-product iff they have the same characteristic (ie iff they have any pre-products at all), in which case it's their common prime subfield.
